# Multi conditions in Case to trigger cells change

Tags: excel, vba

I use this code to make cells change but I feel the Case is too chunky. Can anyone help to make it more neatly. Basically the following conditions trigger the change to happen :
Conditions to trigger the event
firstcell value and secondcell value

Cells values
firstcell value = ("E") or ("N")
secondcell value =("D", "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "G", "K")

and

firstcell value =("N")
secondcell value =("E")

```
Sub PairedCell3()

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim C As Range, rng As Range, rng1 As Range
Set rng = Range("C3", Range("AL" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

With rng.Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

'Make Target and Adjacent Cells Change
For Each C In rng
               Case "ED", "ED1", "ED2", "ED3", "ED4", "ED5", "EG", "EK", _
                "ND", "ND1", "ND2", "ND3", "ND4", "ND5", "NE", "NG", "NK"
                    With C.Resize(, 2)
                        .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
                        .Borders.Weight = xlThick
                        .Borders.Color = RGB(102, 0, 255)
                    End With
                End Select
Next C
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to tag your question for appropriate attention - check the description of the [tag:case] tag (the only one you use) and consider tagging with the relevant programming language _instead_.

Comment: I resolved this already. Thanks